# #1215 - No puede adicionar clave extranjera constraint, no encuentro que esta mal en el codigo

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de importar una base de datos que saque de una pagina web que manejo, ya que con el proveedor de hosting con el que estamos es un robo de tanto que nos cobra y queremos cambiarnos, lo estoy intentando hacer yo porque no es una empresa de CDMX y no queremos que nos cobren una millonada por ayudarnos a cambiarnos de hosting, lo intente pero sale este error:

## 1215 - No puede adicionar clave extranjera constraint

No soy programador y estoy hecho un lio con este error que me salio, si alguien me pudiera ayudar diciéndome que esta mal para corregirlo, por favor.

Ya revise otros posts similares y e intentado cambiando varias cosas pero todos mis intentos son fallidos, estas son las tablas, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho, ya que no tengo idea que este mal:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Table: `gctkkcyx_wc_download_log`
# --------------------------------------------------------


#
# Delete any existing table `gctkkcyx_wc_download_log`
#

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gctkkcyx_wc_download_log`;


#
# Table structure of table `gctkkcyx_wc_download_log`
#

    CREATE TABLE `gctkkcyx_wc_download_log` (
      `download_log_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
      `permission_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `user_ip_address` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`download_log_id`),
      KEY `permission_id` (`permission_id`),
      KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_gctkkcyx_wc_download_log_permission_id` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions` (`permission_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci ;

#
# Data contents of table `gctkkcyx_wc_download_log`
#

#
# End of data contents of table `gctkkcyx_wc_download_log`
# --------------------------------------------------------



y este es el otro:


# --------------------------------------------------------
# Table: `gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions`
# --------------------------------------------------------


#
# Delete any existing table `gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions`
#

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions`;


#
# Table structure of table `gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions`
#

    CREATE TABLE `gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions` (
      `permission_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `download_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
      `product_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `order_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `order_key` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
      `user_email` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
      `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `downloads_remaining` varchar(9) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `access_granted` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `access_expires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `download_count` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`permission_id`),
      KEY `download_order_key_product` (`product_id`,`order_id`,`order_key`(16),`download_id`),
      KEY `download_order_product` (`download_id`,`order_id`,`product_id`),
      KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
      KEY `user_order_remaining_expires` (`user_id`,`order_id`,`downloads_remaining`,`access_expires`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci ;

#
# Data contents of table `gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions`
#

#
# End of data contents of table `gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions`
# --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Saludos lo que te sugiero es primero crear la tabla "gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions".. despues sigues con  "gctkkcyx_wc_download_log"..

Comment: Pues yo he probado tu script y funciona

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego Avila, funciono lo que me dijiste. En lugar de tener primero 
"gctkkcyx_wc_download_log"
y luego
"gctkkcyx_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions"
Lo inverti y ya pude pasar correctamente mi base de datos.
Te lo agradezco mucho!!